# Is it a bug? on solving system of equations

Tags: equation-solving

```
Solve [(((750/(k*v*2))*(1 - e^(-2 k)))/(1 - e^(-k*8)))*e^(-6 k) == 
    50 && (((750/(k*v*2))*(1 - e^(-2 k)))/(1 - e^(-k*6)))*e^(-4 k) == 
    70  , {v, k}
    ] /. e -> E
```

It said `"Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve."`  However, if I put another variable to `Solve` (even if it does not exist) like this: `Solve [.... , {v,k,s}]` it can actually solve the equations. What just happened? is it just a bug or there are anything explanation?

---

Im using Wolfram Mathematica 8.0 and

```
Solve [(((750/(k*v*2))*(1 - E^(-2 k)))/(1 - E^(-k*8)))*E^(-6 k) == 
   50 && (((750/(k*v*2))*(1 - E^(-2 k)))/(1 - E^(-k*6)))*E^(-4 k) == 
   70, {k, v}, Method -> Reduce]
```

does not work for me it keeps running all day and returns

> No more memory available. Mathematica kernel has shut down. Try
>   quitting other applications and then retry.

However, if i let 50 equal variable `S` and solve for `v,k,S` it somehow gives

```
Solve [(((750/(k*v*2))*(1 - e^(-2 k)))/(1 - e^(-k*8)))*e^(-6 k) == 
    S && (((750/(k*v*2))*(1 - e^(-2 k)))/(1 - e^(-k*6)))*e^(-4 k) == 
    70, {v, k, S}] /. e -> E 

v -> 75/(14 (1 + E^(2 k) + E^(4 k)) Log[E^k]), S -> (
 70 (1 + E^(2 k) + E^(4 k)))/(1 + E^(2 k) + E^(4 k) + E^(6 k))
```

which i know `S==50` then I can solve for k and v later on

```
Solve [S == (70 (1 + E^(2 k) + E^(4 k)))/(
    1 + E^(2 k) + E^(4 k) + E^(6 k)), k] /. S -> 50 // N
```

How come putting exact number is more complicated than defining a variable as it could be any numbers and 50 is just one of them

Comment: Per the text on [tag:bugs], it should only be used once the community or WRI has confirmed it is a bug.

Answer (score 7):

When you run your code, you get the warning:

Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

Why not try using Reduce?

```
Reduce[(((750/(k*v*2))*(1 - E^(-2 k)))/(1 - E^(-k*8)))*E^(-6 k) == 
   50 && (((750/(k*v*2))*(1 - E^(-2 k)))/(1 - E^(-k*6)))*E^(-4 k) == 
   70, {v, k}]
```

This gives a clear answer.

Comment: Now, why when using a system, would one want to pay attention to the advice the system gives its users? ;) (+1)

Answer (score 3):

This is just to remind people that (1) you may access `Reduce` in `Solve` through the `Method` option and (2) sometimes the order of the variables matter when constructing a [CAD](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CylindricalDecomposition.html).

This returns a solution in a few seconds

```
Solve[(((750/(k*v*2))*(1 - E^(-2 k)))/(1 - E^(-k*8)))*E^(-6 k) == 
   50 && (((750/(k*v*2))*(1 - E^(-2 k)))/(1 - E^(-k*6)))*E^(-4 k) == 
   70, {k, v}, Method -> Reduce]
```

but this does not (it takes longer I'm willing to wait, several minutes):

```
Solve[(((750/(k*v*2))*(1 - E^(-2 k)))/(1 - E^(-k*8)))*E^(-6 k) == 
   50 && (((750/(k*v*2))*(1 - E^(-2 k)))/(1 - E^(-k*6)))*E^(-4 k) == 
   70, {v, k}, Method -> Reduce]
```