# How can specifying an additional unknown in Solve make it work?

Tags: equation-solving

```
  Solve [(400 E^(-4 k) (1 - E^(-2 k)))/((1 - E^(-6 k)) k v) == 900 && (
    800 E^(-6 k) (1 - E^(-2 k)))/((1 - E^(-8 k)) k v) == 60, {v, k}] // N
```

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve
>
> Solve::inex: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Solve require exact input, providing Solve with an exact version of the system may help

However, if I specified variables to solve to be `{v,k,s}`, `Solve` seems to work just fine despite `s` not existing in the equations at all.

```
  Solve[
    (400 E^(-4 k) (1 - E^(-2 k)))/((1 - E^(-6 k)) k v) == 900 && 
    (800 E^(-6 k) (1 - E^(-2 k)))/((1 - E^(-8 k)) k v) == 60, 
    {v, k,s}] // N
```

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.
>
> Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables

```
{{v -> 0.0000636196 - 0.000117529 I, k -> 1.70058 + 3.14159 I}, 
 {v -> 0.000280738, k -> 1.70058}, 
 {v -> 0.153834 - 6.48714 I, k -> -0.00846644 + 2.08977 I}, 
 {v -> -0.461559 + 12.8837 I, k -> -0.00846644 - 1.05182 I}, 
 {v -> 0.153834 + 6.48714 I, k -> -0.00846644 - 2.08977 I}, 
 {v -> -0.461559 - 12.8837 I, k -> -0.00846644 + 1.05182 I}}
```

Why does specifying another variable, which does not exist, make `Solve` work?

How can I find all the solutions? What commands I should use?

I have tried `Reduce` and it keeps running all day and gives the alert:

> $\qquad $No more memory available.
>   $\qquad $Mathematica kernel has shut down.
>   $\qquad $Try quitting other applications and then retry.

`NSolve` does not work either.

Im using Mathematica version 8.0.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Is it a bug? on solving system of equations](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/123693/9362)

Comment: @Bob Hanlon. Not quite; the OP now explicitely asks for an explanation why adding an irrelevant extra variable to a set of equations helps in finding a solution, something that puzzles me as well. And, just as with the OP, on my system Reduce does not work either.

Comment: @FredSimons - As stated in its documentation, "Solve deals primarily with linear and polynomial equations."  These equations are neither.  However, with version 9 or later `Reduce[eqns, {k, v}, Backsubstitution -> True]` or `Solve[eqns, {k, v}, Method -> Reduce]` both work.

Comment: So it's kind of a bug right? at least for Mathematica version 8 
I think if Mathematica cannot solve then it just cannot solve unless users add specific condition to analyse the the equation and obtain the answer by themselves but why irrelevant extra variable could force Mathematica to find the solutions. Im trying to find  mathematical explanation other than bugs on using Solve commands

Answer (score 5):

Though I am highly surprised by the fact that adding a superfluous variable to a `Solve` command enables `Solve` to find a solution that is otherwise not found, I do not think this can be called a bug. As Bob Hanlon mentions, the documentation states that  `Solve` deals primarily with linear and polynomial equations, and your equations obviously are not. However, `Solve` now can be used for analytic equations on bounded domains.  Unfortunately, your equations are not analytic at `(k,v)=(0,0)`. So one should not be surprised that `Solve` does not work for your equations. But `Solve` can be used with some flexible limitations.

```
equations = {(400 E^(-4 k) (1 - E^(-2 k)))/((1 - E^(-6 k)) k v) == 900, (800 E^(-6 k) (1 - E^(-2 k)))/((1 - E^(-8 k)) k v) == 60 };
```

Let us make these equations analytic:

```
equations2 = equations /. {k -> 1/k, v -> 1/v};
```

Now we can find all real solutions, at a distance at least 10^-4 from the origin:

```
{1/k, 1/v} /. Solve[Join[equations2, {Abs[k] < 10^4, Abs[v] < 10^4}], {k, v}, Reals] 

(* long formula *)

N[%]
(* {{1.70058, 0.000280738}} *)
```

When we replace `Reals` with `Complexes` in the above command, we should get the complex solutions of the equations at a distance of at least `10^-4` from the origin. On my computer, that took too much time, so after 12 minutes I aborted this computation and went to the following way of solving your equations, which essentially is what you would have done with pen and paper.

It is easy to eliminate the variable `v`:

```
Eliminate[equations, v] 
(* -29 E^(2 k)-29 E^(4 k)+E^(6 k)==29 *)
```

Let us restrict ourselves to `| k | < 5` :

```
kvalues = k /. Solve[% && Abs[k] < 5, k]
(* large expression *)
```

This gives the following solutions:

```
Flatten[Table[{k, v} /. Solve[equations, v], {k, kvalues}] , 1] // N
(* {{1.70058,0.000280738},{1.70058 -3.14159 I,0.0000636196 +0.000117529 I},{1.70058 +3.14159 I,0.0000636196 -0.000117529 I},{-0.00846644-1.05182 I,-0.461559+12.8837 I},{-0.00846644-4.19342 I,-0.0962857+3.23233 I},{-0.00846644+2.08977 I,0.153834 -6.48714 I},{-0.00846644+1.05182 I,-0.461559-12.8837 I},{-0.00846644-2.08977 I,0.153834 +6.48714 I},{-0.00846644+4.19342 I,-0.0962857-3.23233 I}} *)
```